# Selenium builder, Run Test Locally is not enabled

Tags: selenium, selenium-builder

I have downloaded selenium builder from http://www.sebuilder.com/     with following configuration
Firefox version 43.0.4
Selenium builder version 3.0.5

After that I have
  Launch the SeleniumBuilder and click the “Manage Plugins” and download the 
  Sauce for Selenium Builder 3 1.0.3
 In  SeleniumBuilder I have  imported the .json script using "Open a script or suite' option. 
 Now under Run option 'Run Test Locally' is not found.

Any additional configuration required to enable 'Run Test Locally’  in selenium builder?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like new Mozilla update have restricted the way old selenium builder ran local test, so developer had to take it out for selenium builder 3. Have a look at this https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/selenium-builder/issues/6